# How to convert String to BigInteger when var contains ".0"

Tags: java, casting, biginteger

I've got a **String** variable that may contain a number such "2015.0".
When I try to convert it to int with

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(myVar)
```

or BigInteger with

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(myVar)
```

I get the error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2015.0"
```

How can I achieve a correct cast?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can parse it as a `BigDecimal` and then convert to `BigInteger`

```
BigInteger bi = new BigDecimal("2015.0").toBigInteger()
```

Just note that you may lose precision information when doing this:

> ...any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded. Note that this conversion can lose information about the precision of the BigDecimal value.
>
> To have an exception thrown if the conversion is inexact (in other words if a nonzero fractional part is discarded), **use the toBigIntegerExact() method.**

As suggested in the quoted javadocs, use `toBigIntegerExact()` to prevent accidental losses of precision such as the one that would result from converting `"2.5"` to `BigInteger` (thanks to [Ole V.V.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54905562/how-to-convert-string-to-biginteger-when-var-contains-0/54905604?noredirect=1#comment96578317_54905604) for this remark).

Comment: Correct. For most purposes I’d prefer `toBigIntegerExact` to catch the case where an exact conversion cannot be done.

Comment: @OleV.V. Then it wouldn't be different to what OP tries, you would only get a different Exception.

Comment: @Tom I get no exception from `new BigDecimal("2015.0").toBigIntegerExact()`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that this is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just parse it to a `double` and then drop the decimal part by casting it to `int`

```
int i = (int) Double.parseDouble(myVar);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't convert a `float` to a `BigInteger`, and your string has a decimal point, so it's automatically considered to be a `float`.  You have a couple of options, but the easiest might be to strip off the decimal portion from the string to get "2015", and then use *that* to construct your `BigInteger`.

That's assuming that the decimal portion of the number doesn't matter, of course.  If it does, consider using `BigDecimal`, instead.